# React - Axios request page and limit not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, limit

Why is this still loading all data and not only first 15?

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    const getHistory = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/payment?page=${page}&limit=${15}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: token },
      });
      setHistory(res.data);
    };
    getHistory();
  }, []);`
```

This is what happens in backend

```
getPayments: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const payments = await Payments.find();
      res.json(payments);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does your backend do with those query params?

Comment: I updated original post

Comment: `getPayments` is not doing anything with `page` & `limit`.

Comment: Ah okay, it's first time i try to work with infinite scroll and i didn't found a tutorial for axios + mongodb infinite scroll. Do you know what I've to add to the backend to make it work?

Comment: Well, what does Payments.find() do? You'll need to modify that code to check `req.params` for the `page` and `limit`, and query your database for a subset of the data instead of all the data.

Comment: const Payments = require('../models/paymentModel');

It's list all my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually retrieve and use your query params in the `getPayments` function:

```
getPayments: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { page, limit } = req.query
    const payments = await Payments.find().skip(page * limit).limit(limit).exec();
    res.json(payments);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
};
```